# HibernateException: Wrong column type after changing column from number to varchar2 in a Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I've got a strange behaviour in Hibernate after changing a column from number to varchar2 in a Oracle Database.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in XXX for column SESSION_TOKEN. Found: varchar2, expected: number(10,0)
```

In my corresponding domain object I changed the variable from Integer to String like this:

```
@Column(name = "SESSION_TOKEN", nullable = true)
private String sessionToken;
```

I already have the following property in the persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

So it seems to me, that there is something like a internal cache which still contains the old description of the table?
Any ideas??
My Environment:
JBoss AS: 7.1.1
Oracle: 11.2

Comment: check if schema validation is enable in your configuration.
`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate`

Comment: I already had the property in the persistence.xml, still not working!

Comment: you changed the data type of column at class level or at DB level?

Comment: Both: First I did a "alter table" to change the column from number to varchar2, after that I changed the domain object from Integer to String.

Comment: try @column(columndefination="char") in your domain object

Comment: Problem solved! Very strange!! After reboot of my laptop the problem was gone! Thanx zombie!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Very strange!! After reboot of my laptop the problem was gone! Thanx zombie!